# React router wont render components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a small piece of code to understand react router, I have set up routes `/`,`/aboutme` and `/contact`. The problem is only the `/` route works, The other routes won't render. There is no error in the console either and the `/` route works at `localhost:8080/#!/` or `localhost:8080/#!` not at `localhost:8080` as I thought it would. I am using **webpack 4** to bundle files. Is there something wrong with my config file that's causing this issue?
I tried accessing routes at
`http://localhost:8080/#!/aboutme`
`http://localhost:8080/#!/contact`
only the root component is rendered in both the cases
`http://localhost:8080/aboutme` throws cannot get/url
`http://localhost:8080/contact` throws cannot get/url

I don't understand what I am doing wrong please take look.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route'

const root= (props) => {
    return (
        <p>hello</p>
    )
}
const about= (props) => {
    return (
        <p>About me -_-</p>
    )
}
const contact= (props) => {
    return (
        <p>contact info</p>
    )
}
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route path="/" exact component={root} />
                <Route path="/aboutme" exact component={about} />
                <Route path="/contact" exact component={contact} />
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

my webpack config

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

Comment: If you add a [`<Link>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link), with `to="/aboutme"` within `root` for example, does it show `about` after you click on the link? The issue may be server-side, because browsers often check with the server first and, unlike the client code, it may not understand what `/aboutme` or `/contact` are supposed to be. Possibly related: [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually/37449679)

Comment: when I use a `<Link>` with `to="/aboutme"` it renders the `about` component at `localhost:8080/aboutme` but yea manually going there or refreshing to page throws `cannot get/url`

Comment: I had been following a tutorial on youtube that was posted on mar'18 and the guy in video had no issues with manually loading the links or refreshing the links after components had rendered  and also the routes were loaded on `localhost:3000` and not on `localhost:3000/#/` or `localhost:3000/#!/` .Did  react-router-dom get updated recently? and he was using yarn on his project and not webpack.

Comment: Has the video tutorial discussed how to host a React app? What you've described so far doesn't seem to indicate that the root of the issue is with React-Router, your Routes, or your components. Rather, it seems to with how you retrieve the app's code and content from `localhost:8080` (i.e. your server, or how you're currently hosting it during development).

Comment: It was a client side app only.[link](https://github.com/techsithgit/react-router) to his repository.

Comment: The project includes `react-scripts`, which has a predefined server via the `react-scripts start` command (or `npm start`, if you [started from `create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v1.1.5/packages/react-scripts/scripts/init.js#L40)). Are you using that or something else for `localhost:8080`?

Comment: I get it now,I had started my app from scratch and not `create-react-app`.....Thanks for all your help Jonathan!

Comment: Are you using webpack-dev-server? You will need to have a fallback URL, so that webpack will always serve your bundle even when it gets a different URL. Have a look at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback - if you're not running the app using `webpack-dev-server`, I'll need a little more context, because no matter what you'll need to re-write the URL if you want to have it work on refresh. What are you using to serve the application?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<Switch />` Component to render only one component for one route and pass exact prop to Route, it will only render if the full path is matched.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Route from "react-router-dom/Route";

const root = props => {
  return <p>hello</p>;
};

const about = props => {
  return <p>About me -_-</p>;
};

const contact = props => {
  return <p>contact info</p>;
};

const pageNotFound = props => {
  return <p>page not found.</p>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={root} exact />
        <Route path="/aboutme" exact component={about} exact />
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={contact} exact />
        <Route component={pageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("index"));
```